# Webservice for JSON post

Tags: php, arrays, json, web-services, post

I am new to web service and new to PHP and MAMP.

I succeeded in writing PHP GET web service but I have no idea about writing the POST web service for PHP in MAMP.

Actually I want to POST a JSON.

Any help will be appreciated heartily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so simple for `rest` webservices, have a look.

```
  <?php
$data = array('foo' => 'bar', 'red' => 'blue');


$ch = curl_init();
$post_values = array( 'json_data' => json_encode( $data ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/server.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_values);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
  echo 'Received raw data' . $data;
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
$data = json_decode( $_POST['json_data'] );
// ... do something ...
header('Content-type: text/json');
print json_encode($response);
?>
```

You can use it to post  JSON data

Comment: Can i use this for JSON Post

Comment: Thank you Mahendra . I will surely look to it